# Removing (cropping) text from image

Tags: python, opencv, keras, ocr

I am trying to implement an image recognition program and I need to remove (or "crop") all text, present on the image, so for example from that:

[image]

to that:

[image]

I already tried the Keras OCR method, but firstly I don't need the background blur I simply need to delete the text, and secondly it takes a lot of time and CPU power. Is there an easier way to detect those text regions and simply crop them out of the picture?

Comment: Approach #1: load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold, find contours, filter using contour area threshold, effectively remove all letters/characters by filling them in with drawContours

Comment: Approach #2: find horizontal and vertical contours. Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold, create horizontal and vertical structuring element, then isolate horizontal/vertical lines to remove letters/characters

Answer (score 0):

One way is to detect the text with findContours - the ones with an area < threshold are letters, then paint over these areas, or/and first find their bounding rectangle and paint a big one.

[Text Extraction from image after detecting text region with contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597099/text-extraction-from-image-after-detecting-text-region-with-contours)

There is also pytesseract to detect letters and their region, but I guess it will be heavier than the contours.

Here is an example project where I worked with pytesseract: [How to obtain the best result from pytesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277845/how-to-obtain-the-best-result-from-pytesseract/65278387#65278387)